# Do you know a bit.ly API Php Script example?

Tags: php, bit.ly

Do you have a php script that use the API from bit.ly ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going from Ceejayoz's Example, you can make it a one liner!

```
$short_url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=bitlyusername&apiKey=bitlyapikey&longUrl=".urlencode("http://example.com")."&format=json"))->data->url;
```

Comment: Well, technically you can make anything in PHP a one liner. But that's what you get when you have a valid line delimiter like the semicolon. Take that Python!

Answer (score 7):

I just [googled](http://google.com) your question : [Example code](http://www.x-pose.org/blog/144)

```
/* Example code */  
$link = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";  

print getSmallLink($link);  

function getSmallLink($longurl){  
// Bit.ly  
$url = "http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&longUrl=$longurl&login=YOURLOGIN&apiKey=YOURAPIKEY&format=json&history=1";  

$s = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);  
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
$result = curl_exec($s);  
curl_close( $s );  

$obj = json_decode($result, true);  
return $obj["results"]["$longurl"]["shortUrl"];  
}
```

Comment: +1, haha you actually *linked* to google.com?

Comment: well, you never know ;-)

Comment: wjat is "yourapikey"? i only got client id and client secret

Answer (score 4):

It's a [very simple API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#Getting_Started).

```
$long_url = urlencode('http://example.com/');

$bitly_login = 'username';
$bitly_apikey = 'YOUR API KEY';

$bitly_response = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login={$bitly_login}&apiKey={$bitly_apikey}&longUrl={$long_url}&format=json"));

$short_url = $bitly_response->data->url;
```